# How to call a function when a user logs into the backend?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I need to set some session variables when the user logs into the backend. A logical choice would be to listen for the `backend.user.login` event in my plugins `boot()` method, but for some reason it does not work (no sure if it is supposed to)

```
    Event::listen('backend.user.login', function($user) {
        # do something
    });
```

So the question is, how can I execute some code when the user logs in?

Comment: Does any code executed into your plugins `boot()` function?

Comment: Yes, everything else works

Comment: Can you debug {projectdir}/modules/backend/models/User.php at 121 line, to check that event was fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this feature it's a **hidden** trick but you have to set the `$elevated` property true.

```
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

    public $elevated = true; //this thing :D
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen('backend.user.login', function ($user) {
            \Log::info('now WORKS :D');
        });
    }
}
```

It's seems that to be able to listen backend events it's an elevated privilege

`/**
     * @var boolean Determine if this plugin should have elevated privileges.
     */`